# Lubuntu and XP file transfer

Tags: files, sharing

I now have Lubuntu and XP on my laptop so I am wondering how ( if ) I can transfer files etc from XP to Lubuntu.
I realize I could write them all to disc and then presumably load into Lubuntu but I am hoping there is an easier way.

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
disk /dev/sda:40.0gb 40007761920 bytes
255 heads. 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders. total 78140160 sectors

units = sectors of 1 * 512 + 512 bytes
sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size ( minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier : 0xcccdcccd

   device boot          start      end     blocks   id   system
/dev/sda1  *               63   54523363  27261650+  7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2             68871600  78140159   4634280  12   Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sda3             54523902  68870143   7173121   5   Extended
/dev/sda5             54523904  67844095   6660096  83   Linux
/dev/sda6             67846144  68870143    512000  82   Linux swap /Solaris
```

Partition tables are not in disk order

Comment: Start Lubuntu and access your XP partition with the filemanger (pcmanfm). Lubuntu can access NTFS partitions but Windows XP can not access your Lubuntu partition (ext2/3/4).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.Open Disks

[image]

2.Mount the NTFS (Windows) partition

[image]

3.Access the windows partition

[image]

Normally it should be possible only with the filemanger PCManFM.

[image]

Comment: Bingo ! Worked perfectly, thanks for all your efforts - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally Lubuntu automounts existing FAT32 or NTFS partitions so you should see it on the left navigation bar of PCmanFM file manager(e.g. 10GB volume) click on it and copy your needed data to the Lubuntu partition.

If it doesn't work then you can mount the partition under Lubuntu using following steps
First you need to check your Windows partition using:

```
sudo blkid
```

and check the TYPE column for ntfs or vfat. You should see something like:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="1A77BE0E386A513F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="00023f15-01"
```

Depending on your filesystem use one of the following commands:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /media
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media
```

Replace /dev/sda1 with the device you get from the blkid output. Then you can use PCManFM to copy data to your Linux partition.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble but I really need some more basic help.

Comment: Did you try to follow my first advice from my answer ? Open PCmanFM file manager and you should see on the left navigation bar  the Windows partition called something like (e.g. 10GB volume) click on it and copy your needed data to the Lubuntu partition.

Comment: Yes I did but there is nothing there that is a windows partition. I have looked at everything in the navigation bar and I am sure that there is no partition. I am reasonably ok with my computer but I have never had two OS on one m/c. Sorry if I am a bit slow here.

Comment: @user283447 Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal on Lubuntu), [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/469534/edit)